# wicket auto refresh datatable caches values

Tags: wicket

I am using a datatable inside a panel and the panel is set to autorefresh every 60 sec. the panel occassionally seems to pull values that are not passed to the Object. I am using PropertyColumn to add columns to the data table. Is there a way to disable cache in wicket or data table specifically

I have a webservice that returns a list of contacts. This list is passed to all the panels below

In LoadContactPanel
   new ContactPanel(ViewPanel.getContentPanelId() , getContactListModel());

```
public IModel<List<Contact>> getContactListModel() {
    List<Contact> listofmodels = //get list from a webservice call
    return new ListModel<>(listofmodels);
}
```

In ContactPanel I load another panel called AccordianPanel

The AccordianPanel contains a RepeatingView

Each RepeatingView is a panel and in the panel, I am adding a DefaultDataTable

The source of the DefaultDataTable is ContactDataProvider that extends SortableDataProvider

This is the code of the model method in ContactDataProvider

```
@Override
public IModel<Contact> model(final Contact object) {

    return new AbstractReadOnlyModel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

         @Override
        public Object getObject() {
                return object;
        } 
    };
}
```

In this situation, what should be converted to a LoadableDetachableModel. The one that is returned from the webservice or the one in ContactDataProvider

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are loading data from a model which is stored in memory. You should use `LoadableDetachableModel` to load data each time component is rendered. Not sure that it answers your question as you provided too few details, please show some code.

Comment: But then you should make sure the 'detach' is called; otherwise you will just end up in the same situation.. If the model is not the default model, you could do this in the 'onDetach' method of the component.

Comment: @RobAu Not sure, but I think you are saying something wrong. `LoadableDetachableModel` has abstract `load` method which should retrieve data from db. The method is invoked each time page is rendered, as the object retrieved is not stored in a memory between requests (i.e. detached).

Comment: load() is invoked when the model is detached. The model itself knows nothing of the page it is on. If the model is used as default model in a Component, the component calls the detach() on its IModel. If you create a LDM that is not directly (or via wrapper models like PropertyModel) used in a Component, the detach() will never be called. The modelObject and attach boolean is transient, so on Serialization/Deserialization the attached state will be 'reset' and the modelObject reloaded the next time getObject() is called.